# Android Location Service doesn't stop on home button

Tags: android

I have a service that runs to get user current location through LocationListener. I stop the service on the activity's onDestroy() but this method is only called when the user hits the back button to exit the app.
I want the service to stop both when the user hits the back button to exit and when they hit the home button. However, as far as i know, there's no way to intercept the home button. How do people deal with this issue?
Is it normal to leave the location listener running after the user hits the home button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use onPause() instead on onDestroy()

Comment: But that is called when i go from one activity to another. i think the location service should be running whenever the app is opened? The location listener updates  me with new location every 20 minutes. hmm

Comment: Ok, so then I'd reccomend creating an Application class and using that to control the life of the location listener

Comment: Use ActivityLifecycleCallback to determine if any activities are still running and stop the service when the last one finishes https://baroqueworksdev.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-to-use-activitylifecyclecallbacks.html

Comment: Thank you. i think i've figured out a better solution than using Service. I'm going to keep the time stamp of the last location update and keep that in the database and also shared preference. i just access shared preference time stamp to see how long it's been and if long enough call to update location and timestamp.